# Ruby: constant, module, hash

Tags: ruby, module, constants

I'm a few months into learning Ruby, and right now I'm trying to build a South Korean/North Korean/English dictionary type of thing. I'm feeding it a text file that has all the words.

So far I've got:

```
module Dictionary

  DICTIONARY = []

end

class File

  include Dictionary

  def self.convert(file)
    readlines(file).each do |line|
      south, north, meaning = line.split(',')
      DICTIONARY << { :south => south, :north => north, :meaning => meaning }
    end
  end

end

File.convert("dictionary.txt")

Dictionary::DICTIONARY.sort_by { |word| word[:north] }.each do |word|
  puts "#{word[:south]} is #{word[:north]} in North Korean. They both mean #{word[:meaning]}"
end
```

My question is:

1) Is it unnecessary for me to make a separate module for the array? (I was mostly just trying to experiment with mixing in modules and classes)

2) Is using a constant for the array the right move? I guess my thought process was that I wanted the array to be able to be accessed from outside, but to be honest I don't really know what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "from the outside". What type of application are you building?

Comment: You can create a `instance_variable` with dictionary instead of `constant`

Comment: I'd suggest not pollute class `File`, because it is a general purpose class for reading/writing all kinds of files, not just for your specific use-case.

Answer (score 6):

Since your dictionary is loaded from a file, it's better to have a class instead of a module so each file can be parsed to a separate dictionary.

```
class Dictionary
  attr_reader :content

  def initialize
    @content = []
  end

  def self.load(path)
    instance = new
    File.open(path) do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|
        instance.content << %i(south, north, meaning).zip(line.split(','))
      end
    end
    instance
  end
end
```

Besides, you can see I didn't patch the `File` class because `File` is not only for creating dictionaries, but for all sorts of file manipulation.

Comment: You should to return `instance` variable from `self.load` method.

Comment: @LukasBaliak Thank you. Code is fixed.

Comment: @Aetherus Question: could you explain the 'instance = new' and 'instance.content' part?

Comment: `instance = new` is equivalent to `instance = self.new`, where `self` refers to the class in class methods. So it's equivalent to `instance = Dictionary.new`.